# Calculating the value of a unit in a game

Tags: excel, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

I'm currently working on a game where each unit has a value for health, shields and agility as well as a certain number of six types of weapon.

e.g. Unit B has 2 lasers, 2 heavy lasers, and 1 missile launcher, no ion blaster, no heavy ion blaster, no nuclear missiles, 5 health, 2 shield, and 40 agility.

I have gone through a good 20 different algorithms trying to get MS Excel to balance these all these factors to give the ship a score. My current algorithm works great for some of the smaller units, but gets very unbalanced with the bigger units

Each ship has a damage value, where each type of weaponry is multiplied by the damage of that weapon and added together.

```
damage = weapon1*damage1 + weapon2*damage2 + ...
```

The damage value is multiplied by health + 2*shield + 2*agility. Agility and shield are multiplied to give them weight over health (a unit cant lose health if it can't be hit). I also subtract the cost of the unit. So my current equation for one of my units looks like:

```
value = damage*(health + 2*shield + 2*agility) - 3*cost
```

Here are some examples:

- Unit 1 - 1 laser, 1 health, 93 agility, and costs 1. Total score is 233.
- Unit 2 - 2 lasers, a missile launcher, and 3 health, but only 76 agility. Score is 200.
- Unit 3 - 6 lasers, 30 health and 15 shields, 37 agility - scores 585.

I want the scores of unit 3 to be higher, but the scores for units 1 and 2 are pretty good. Can anyone suggest a better equation that will smooth out the values?

Comment: You aren't being very clear as to your goal here. Are you trying to balance the units by changing the damage each weapon does? Or is it the number of different weapons of each ship? Or the cost thereof? Or is it something else? ...

Comment: Each unit has a different number of weapons that all do the same damage (per weapon) - that is why F...L are multiplied by N58...N64. The problem is that =ROUND(W*(M+2N+2O),0)-3R comes up with values that are great for the lower units but ridiculously high or low for the better units. I'm looking for a better formula that will flatten out these bumps.

Comment: OK, say you have a better formula, what are you going to do with it then? I.e. what is your ultimate goal?

Comment: I want the formula to define just how able each unit is, so a higher number means that that unit can destroy units with lesser numbers . Basically simple game mechanics.

Comment: So you just assume that the unit stats you have are already balanced and it's the formula's fault that it's not showing that? What if the formula you have above is OK but the units' stats are designed poorly and unbalanced? If I were in your situation, I would do exactly what you have done so far: come up with a formula that makes sense to me and tweak the stats so they all have the same score. Then use playtesting to really test if they are balanced and further tweak as needed.

Comment: Each type of unit has roughly the same weapons loadout and health/shield/agility, but one of the medium units compared to the unit it would be fighting  (approx. equally) have values of 700 and 1057. The higher value unit has 2 more lasers, but lower health, shield, agility.  Two medium units that should have vastly different values have approx. the same W, yet the should-be-weaker unit's superior agility makes up for it's lack of health/shields. All I am asking for is a different formula that would account for the various stats more accurately.

Comment: As it stands, this question is extremely hard to answer. We don't really know what you are doing or what you are trying to achieve. You need to help us out here. Give us some examples of ships where your formula works and examples of where it doesn't work. Tell us why you think the score for a unit is wrong.

Comment: Unit 1 - 1 laser, 1 health, 93 agility, and costs 1. Total score is 233, following =ROUND((((((F4*$N$58)+(G4*$N$59)+(H4*$N$60)+(I4*$N$63)+(J4*$N$61)+(K4*$N$62)+(L4*$N$64))^2)/2)*((2*N4)+(M4)))+(2.5*O4),0)    Unit 2 - 2 lasers, a missile launcher, and 3 health, but only 76 agility - score is 200. Unit 3 has 6 lasers, 30 health and 15 shields, 37 agility - scores 585. I want the scores of unit 3 to be higher, but the scores for units 1 and 2 are pretty good.

Comment: You've changed your algorithm, where did the squared sum divided by two come from? It's still difficult to tell what's going on because I don't know what N58-N64 are (you could give them better names as well). My best guess is that the agility score is the culprit, it seems to vary over a larger range than shields and health. Try tweaking the multiplier down a bit.

Comment: I've edited you question so people can see what it is you're trying to do. I still don't know what some of the details of your algorithm are so please go in and change anything that's not correct.

Comment: Thanks Stompchicken - the squared was an attempt at flattening out the differences. @Orangepips - I'll try that for each part, but I agree - the agility seems to be the problem right now, but none of the modifiers change the formula enough to make a huge difference, even combined with damage changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think a [genetic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming) algorithm is a good approach to solving the issue you describe. Genetic programming evolves an algorithm's computations through iteration to minimize a cost function. This is done by creating a set of "mutations" to apply to the algorithm, for instance your idea of decreasing by the cost of the unit as 3R could be one of the mutations. The cost function would be something that increases/decreases relative to the concept of balance. Mutations would be evaluated in light of this cost function.

See the book [Programming Collective Intelligence](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325) for Python code to do this type of problem solving.

Comment: This seems like a good idea, but how would you go about applying this to Excel without altering the formula for each iteration of unit?

Comment: If you ultimately want to this in Excel, I would set up my inputs in Excel. Use Python to read those in and do a genetic algorithm iterations. Output the best set of mutations. Take the mutations and create the Excel formula.

Comment: Building on the chain above, @The Snypr: you need to analyze the your formula and tease out the each part that can vary, for instance a multiplier for agility. Identify a number of candidate possibilities for this piece, which could be as simple as a value times a multiplier (e.g. agility * 2), but also much more complex (i.e. if-then-else sort of logic), and run this through the approach I've described.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is similar to my [cloud balancing example](http://blog.athico.com/2010/10/planning-processing-in-cloud.html) (open source, java). Just replace Computer by Unit and Process by Weapon.